# Can't map List<UUID> to database UUID[] Couldn't determine JDBCType for class java.util.UUID

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I have following **table definition:**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
       id UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() PRIMARY KEY,
       result UUID []    
);
```

**Entity definition:**

```
@Table("my_table ")
public class MyTable {

    @Id
    private UUID id;
    
    private List<UUID> result;
    //get set
}
```

**Repository:**

```
@Repository
public interface MytableRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyTable, UUID> {
}
```

Start code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJdbcAuditing
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);

        MytableRepository mytableRepository = applicationContext.getBean(MytableRepository.class);
        MyTable myTable = new MyTable();
        myTable.setResult(Arrays.asList(UUID.randomUUID()));

        mytableRepository.save(myTable);
    }
```

Error is:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't determine JDBCType for class java.util.UUID
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:219)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultJdbcTypeFactory.createArray(DefaultJdbcTypeFactory.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.BasicJdbcConverter.writeJdbcValue(BasicJdbcConverter.java:306)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.addConvertedValue(DefaultDataAccessStrategy.java:560)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.addConvertedPropertyValue(DefaultDataAccessStrategy.java:548)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.lambda$getParameterSource$2(DefaultDataAccessStrategy.java:462)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:360)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PersistentEntity.doWithAll(PersistentEntity.java:255)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.getParameterSource(DefaultDataAccessStrategy.java:440)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.insert(DefaultDataAccessStrategy.java:112)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateChangeExecutionContext.executeInsertRoot(JdbcAggregateChangeExecutionContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.execute(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:66)
    ... 43 more
```

How can I fix it ?

**P.S.**

spring boot version is 2.6.2

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.2' apply false
```

**P.S.2**

I tried to do some changes:

```
 ...
 private List<String> result;
 ...


CREATE TABLE my_table (
       id UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() PRIMARY KEY,
       result varchar[]    
);
```

And it works properly but I would like to have array of UUID

Comment: Don't store references to other tables in arrays. Just don't.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe I have no reason to have separated table with single column

Comment: That table would have two columns, and the reason would be precisely to make your task simple and performant.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe in my use case I will request only one row from that table so I am not sure about performance optimazations you mentioned

Comment: Doesn't the mere fact that you are asking this question indicate that such a solution is unnecessarily complicated?

Comment: @Laurenz Albe As I mentioned in the topic - varchar[] is working. I don't understand why it doesn't work for UUID. Looks like a bug for me